# Fragment getArguments (in onResume) returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to send some data from a Activity to Fragment.

I need to get the data in the **onResume** method of the fragment but I guess that`s not possible?

Arguments can only be received in onCreate()?

Activity:

```
public void someMethod() {
String someString = "test";

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("message", someString);
   VFragment.getInstance().setArguments(bundle);
}
```

Fragment:

```
 public class VFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public static VFragment getInstance() {
            return VFragment_.builder().build();
        }

        public VFragment() {
        }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String receive = getArguments().getString("message");
        Log.v(TAG, receive); // NULL
    }
}
```

Comment: What is getInstance() ?

Comment: save args in oncreate and use it onresume

Comment: @Wizard I edited my code.

Comment: @Jaydeep the Fragment is already created, I need to use onResume as stated

Comment: The fragments onResume() or onPause() will be called only when the Activities onResume() or onPause() is called. They are tightly coupled to the Activity.

Comment: fragment life cycle: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

Alright I don't know what is `builder()` and `build` but this is good practice...

```
public static VFragment newInstance(String text) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putExtrs("message", text)
        VFragment mF = new VFragment();
        mF.setArguments(b);
        return mF;
    }
```

Try this out.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of my code:

- `Fragment` 1

  ```
                      reservation_main_data reservation_main_data = new reservation_main_data();
                      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                      bundle.putCharSequence(bundle_string, txt_results_experience.getText()); //Sending the experience name clicked to another fragment
                      reservation_main_data.setArguments(bundle);
                      FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                      manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout_secundary, reservation_main_data, reservation_main_data.getTag()).commit();
  ```
- `Fragment` 2

  `Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();`

`if (bundle != null) {
            CharSequence myInt = bundle.getCharSequence(bundle_string);
            txt_results_experience.setText(String.valueOf(myInt));
        }`

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for everyone who responded and tried to help.
My mistake that I forgot to mention that I use Android Annotations.

The proper way to do this with annotations is:

*Set a FragmentArg in your 'targetFragment':*

```
@FragmentArg
String receiveA;
```

*Make the receiver method of the Fragment:*

```
public static VFragment getInstance(String message) {
        // Do something with String message
        return VFragment_.builder().receiveA(message).build();
    }
```

*Make the call in the 'source' Activity to send the data:*

```
VFragment.getInstance("This is a test");
```

*Result in targetFragment:*

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v(TAG, message); // Prints 'This is a test'
}
```